# Brainfuck interpreter in C

Tags: c, interpreter, brainfuck

This is my *bare-bones* Brainfuck interpreter in C using lots of unixisms. What improvements can I make (with respect to the clarity of code, or obvious features to add)?

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void error(char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", msg);
}

enum { MEMSIZE = 30000 };

//unsigned char *mem;
unsigned char mem[MEMSIZE];
unsigned char *ptr;
unsigned char *prog;
size_t progsize;

int init(char *progname) {
    int f,r;
    struct stat fs;
    ptr = mem;// = calloc(MEMSIZE, 1);
    f = open(progname, O_RDONLY);
    assert(f != -1);
    r = fstat(f, &fs);
    assert(r == 0);
    prog = mmap(NULL, progsize = fs.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, f, 0);
    assert(prog != NULL);
    return 0;
}

/* As requested, a little more commentary on this, admittedly bizarre, function.
findmatch receives the current instruction-pointer and a bracket character 
for which the "match" is desired. It returns a new instruction-pointer.
*/
int findmatch(int ip, char src){
    char *q, *p="[]";
    int i, defer, dir[]= { 1, -1 };
    i = strchr(p,src)-p;  // at this point, if(src=='[') i=0; else if(src==']') i=1;
    ip+=dir[i];           // ie. if(src=='[') ++ip else if(src==']') --ip
                          // so dir[i] tells us which direction we're going
    // next, we reuse the same idiom to check each character as we scan.
    // defer counts up or down as we encounter [ and ] and finally reaches 0
    // when the match is found.
    for (defer=dir[i]; defer!=0; ip+=dir[i]) {
        if (ip<0||ip>=progsize) error("mismatch");   // check exceeded bounds
        if (q = strchr(p,prog[ip])) {   // if the char is a bracket
            int j = q-p;                // j is 0 or 1
            defer+=dir[j];              // adjust the 'defer' level
        }
    }
    return ip - dir[i];  // return new ip value (one past the matched bracket)
}

int run() {
    int ip;
    for(ip = 0; ip>=0 && ip<progsize; ip++)
        switch(prog[ip]){
        case '>': ++ptr; break;
        case '<': --ptr; break;
        case '+': ++*ptr; break;
        case '-': --*ptr; break;
        case '.': putchar(*ptr); break;
        case ',': *ptr=getchar(); break;
        case '[': /*while(*ptr){*/
                  if (!*ptr)
                      ip=findmatch(ip,'[')-1; // modified because run does ip++ 
                  break;
        case ']': /*}*/
                  if (*ptr)
                      ip=findmatch(ip,']')-1;
                  break;
        }

    return 0;
}

int cleanup() {
    //free(mem);
    ptr = NULL;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    init(argc > 1? argv[1]: NULL);
    run();
    cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ehrm.. `init` has some issues. It's kinda stupid to arrange to pass a NULL pointer if there's no filename, and then pass that NULL pointer to `open` and try to `assert` afterwords. I suppose *readability* might be improved by putting `main` at the top so you can just glance at it and scratch it off straightaway. It would also put it next to `init` which immediately follows in the calling sequence. ... On the otherhand, experienced C readers will naturally scan the whole file to find main. ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Braces

First of all, *curses* to you for omitting the braces for the loop in `run()`.  I wasted a lot of time debugging a problem after I added some instrumentation code before the `switch`.

### Error handling

Your assertions are inappropriate.  Assertions are a way to redundantly state what the programmer knows *must* be true due to reasoning.  They are not an error-handling mechanism.  If the program is compiled with assertions disabled, then all of your "error handling" goes out the window.

A better idiom for error handling would be putting every call that might fail in an `if` condition, and bailing out if it fails.

```
int init(const char *progname) {   // const would be good
    int f, r;
    struct stat fs;
    ptr = mem;// = calloc(MEMSIZE, 1);
    if (!(f = open(progname, O_RDONLY))) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (0 != (r = fstat(f, &fs))) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (!(prog = mmap(NULL, progsize = fs.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, f, 0))) {
        return -1;
    }
    …
```

To follow through, you should handle the error in `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (-1 == init(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : NULL)) {
        perror(NULL);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int err = run();
    cleanup();
    return (err == 0) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

### Looping

Your `findmatch()` is not only hard to read, it's also inefficient.  You can improve both issues by scanning the program just once to build a jump table.

```
int *jumps;

static int matchbrackets(int offset) {
    for (; offset < progsize; offset++) {
        int close;
        switch (prog[offset]) {
        case ']':
            return offset;
        case '[':
            close = matchbrackets(offset + 1);
            if (close < 0) {
                return close;   // mismatch
            }
            jumps[offset] = close;
            jumps[close] = offset;
            offset = close;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Add the initialization code to `init()` (and the corresponding deallocation in `cleanup()`):

```
if (!(jumps = malloc(progsize))) {
    return -1;
}
memset(jumps, -1, progsize);  // Mark all jumps as illegal
matchbrackets(0);             // Find legal jumps
```

Then the `run()` loop looks like:

```
int run() {
    for (int ip = 0; ip < progsize; ip++) {  // <-- better style
        switch (prog[ip]) {
        …
        case '[': if (!*ptr) ip = jumps[ip]; break;
        case ']': if ( *ptr) ip = jumps[ip]; break;
        }
        if (ip < 0) {
            error("mismatch");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're right, it is bad practice in any programming language besides C to omit the braces in a for loop. The reader of the code won't be able to see where the loop ends. But, the statement "curses to you" is kinda mean, so I don't think you should use that. The OP does have a lot of bad practices in his/her program, so I applaud you for addressing that.

Answer (score 8):

My biggest complaint on readability would be your `findmatch()` function. There are too many non-descriptive variables (i.e. `i`, `j`, `p`, etc). Changing the names to be more descriptive, or adding some comments to elaborate on what you're trying to do would help a lot.